# How to install Diaspora in Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diaspora

I am trying to install [Diaspora](http://github.com/diaspora/diaspora). When I `bundle install` in Windows, I encounter some problems which include

```
Fetching http://github.com/BadMinus/devise.git
C:/Ruby Installation/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.2/lib/bundler/ \
source.rb:550:in ``': No such file or directory - git clone \
"http://github.com/BadMinus/devise.git" \
"C:/RubyInstallation/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/bundler/ \
git/devise-d0ffd5c55896afd260298fd75c36924c72f6636c" --bare --no-hardlinks \
(Errno::ENOENT)
```

I also looked into the forums and tried the solutions posted there but they were of little help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that this is not gem specific. I'm having the exact same problem on Windows 7 with the authlogic gem. So it seems to be a bundler error. Also, I'm using Ruby 1.9.2, so that doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error (and in hindsight it's quite obvious): the gem you're trying to install apparently is to be installed from github. The consequence is that you'll have to run the `bundle install` command from the Git Bash command line. You seem to be trying to run the `bundle install` from a regular command line, but in that environment, the `git` command does not work.

Comment: So, how does one fix it?  git is present in the system PATH environment variable already...

Answer (score 0):

diaspora is currently not for windows. You can only install in on unix based OS
For more information check this out https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Installation